# Guardar datos de un formulario PHP

Tags: php

Nesesito recibir datos de un formulario por metodo POST, tengo un Controlador en la Carpeta Controlador.

Codigo
Controlador/Controlador

```
  <?php
require '../Modelo/Controlador.php';
//Llegan datos de formulario por metodo POST y se guardan
  $habitantes =new Controlador();
  $habitantes->agregarHabitante($_POST['identificacion'],$_POST['nombres'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['apto'], $_POST['interior'],   $_POST['telefono'],$_POST['correo']);



   $egresos = new Controlador();
   $egresos->crearComprobante($_POST['Codigo'], $_POST['Concepto'],  $_POST['Valor'],$_POST['Observaciones'],$_POST['PagadoA'] ,$_POST['Cheque'] ,$_POST['Efectivo'] , $_POST['Banco'], $_POST['ElaboradoPor'], $_POST['identificacion']);
```

el problema es que para que los datos de un formulario se inserten a la BD debo comentar uno de los 2 codigo.

Codigo del controlador del Modelo
Modelo/Controlador

```
<?php
require 'GestorEgresos.php';
require 'GestorHabitantes.php';
require 'Conexion.php';
require 'Egresos.php';
require 'Habitantes.php';

class Controlador{

public function crearComprobante($codigo, $concepto, $valor, $observaciones, $pagadoA, $cheque, $efectivo, $banco, $elaboradoPor, $identificacion){
    $Egresos = new Egresos($codigo, $concepto, $valor, $observaciones, $pagadoA, $cheque, $efectivo, $banco, $elaboradoPor, $identificacion);
    $GestorEgresos=new GestorEgresos();
    $registro = $GestorEgresos->crearComprobante($Egresos);
    if($registro >0){
        echo "Comprobante de Egresos creado Correctamente...";
    }else{
        echo "Error al crear el Comprobante...";
    }
}

public function agregarHabitante($identificacion, $nombres, $apellidos, $apto, $interior, $telefono, $correo){
    $Habitantes = new Habitantes($identificacion, $nombres, $apellidos, $apto,  $interior, $telefono, $correo);
    $GestorHabitantes = new GestorHabitantes();
    $registros = $GestorHabitantes->agregarHabitantes($Habitantes);
    if($registros >0){
        echo "Habitante Agregado Correctamente...";
    }else{
        echo "Error! El Habitante ya existe...";
    }
}
```

No se si me haya hecho entender.

Comment: Mm tal vez podrias hacer una sola funcion uniendo las dos logicas de crearComprobante() y agregarHabitante() y pasando todas las variables a esa nueva funcion.

Comment: ¿Cómo hace la llamada a los métodos vía Ajax o por formulario simple ?

Comment: prueba reemplazar los require por require_once

Answer (score 1):

Bueno encontré la solución de la siguiente manera.
El problema era que se estaban enviando los datos del primer formulario que encontraba el controlador.
Para solucionarlo lo hice con isset, dejo el código.

```
<?php

require '../Modelo/Controlador.php';
//Llegan datos de formulario por metodo POST y se guardan

$controlador = new Controlador();
if(isset($_GET["accion"])){
if($_GET["accion"]=="crearComprobante"){
    $controlador->crearComprobante( $_POST['Concepto'],  $_POST['Valor'],$_POST['Observaciones'],$_POST['PagadoA'] ,$_POST['Cheque'] ,$_POST['Efectivo'] , $_POST['Banco'], $_POST['ElaboradoPor'], $_POST['identificacion']);
}elseif($_GET["accion"]== "crear"){
    $controlador->agregarHabitante($_POST['identificacion'], $_POST['nombres'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['apto'], $_POST['interior'], $_POST['telefono'],$_POST['correo']);
}

}
?>
```